# .Bat file to copy txt files without changing extension?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I need to copy all `.TXT` files under a directory [subfolders included] and copy them to another directory [without subfolders] but I can't change the extension of the files after I copy them, for example to `.OLD` or `.TXT.OLD`. Is that possible to do it via .bat file? Is there any special tool to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) instead:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\path\to\root\dir -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".txt"} | % {Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination C:\path\to\target\dir}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the root part of the filename and then append your own extension in the rename.  For example, to demonstrate that *(you don't say you're having any issue with the logic of the actual process, just the extension manipulation, so that's what I'm addressing)*:

```
FOR %%I IN (*.txt) DO REN %%I %%~nI.txt.old
```

This will take all `*.txt` files in the current directory and rename them to the same root + extension `.txt.old`.  There's a possible complication in that the resulting filename cannot already exist in a rename, so you may want to put it into a more complex loop such as:

```
FOR %%I IN (*.txt) DO (
    [do other stuff here]
    IF EXIST %%~nI.txt.old DEL %%~nI.txt.old
    REN %%I %%~nI.txt.old
)
```

Try `for /?` at a command prompt and check out the last part of it for the syntax of filename/path substitution parameters